# Want to find the maximum of an unnormalised density function.

Tags: statistics

Assume $\{Y_i\}$ are iid generated from a gamma distribution with shape $\alpha$ and rate $\beta$, $n$ is the number of $Y_i$. I have an unnormalised density function about $\alpha$ as follow:

$$f(\alpha) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha n}}{\Gamma(\alpha)^n} \prod_{i = 1}^n Y_i^{\alpha}$$

where $\{ Y_i\}$, $n$ and $\beta$ are known. So my goal is to find the maximum of    $f(\alpha)$. If a finite $T$ could be proved to be greater or equal than $f(\alpha)$ is also good, i.e $f(\alpha) \le T$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for that I did not express it clearly. I want to find the maximum of $f(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approximate solution.

From
$f(\alpha) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha n}}{\Gamma(\alpha)^n} \prod_{i = 1}^n Y_i^{\alpha}$,
let $F$ be its log
(and lazily using $a$ for $\alpha$, 
$b$ for $\ln\beta$,
and $z_i$ for $\ln y_i$),
$F(a) 
= anb-n\ln\Gamma(a)+ \sum_{i = 1}^n a z_i
$.

From Stirling,
$\ln \Gamma(a)
\approx a\ln a -a +C+\ln a/2
$
(where
$C = \frac12\ln \pi$),
so,
setting
$W
=\frac1{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n z_i
$

$\begin{array}\\
F(a) 
&\approx anb-n(a \ln a - a + C+\ln a/2)+ \sum_{i = 1}^n a z_i\\
&= anb-na \ln a + na -n C-n\ln a/2+anW\\
&= na(b+1+W)- na\ln a - nC-n\ln a/2\\
\end{array}
$

Differentiating,

$\begin{array}\\
F'(a)
&\approx n(b+1+W)- n(1+\ln a) -n/(2a)\\
&=n(b+W)- n\ln a -n/(2a)\\
\end{array}
$

As a first approximation,
neglecting the
$1/a$ term
(which assumes that
$a$ is moderately large),
$F'(a)
\approx nb+nW- n\ln a
$
.

The extremum is when
$F'(a) = 0$,
or
$nb+nW
=n\ln a
$
or
$\ln a
=b+W
$
or
$a 
= e^{b+W}
$.

At this $a$,

$\begin{array}\\
F(a)
&\approx ne^{b+W}(b+1+W)- n(b+W)e^{b+W} - nC-n(b+W)/2\\
&=ne^{b+W}(b+1+W- (b+W)) - nC-n(b+W)/2\\
&=ne^{b+W} - nC-n(b+W)/2\\
&=n(e^{b+W} - C-(b+W)/2)\\
\end{array}
$

To get a more accurate $a$,
you could do a Newton's iteration of
$a 
= a-F'(a)/F''(a)
$.
For this,
since
$F''(a)
\approx -n/a+n/(2a^2)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
F'(a)/F''(a)
&\approx (n(b+W)- n\ln a -n/(2a))/(-n/a+n/(2a^2))\\
&= ( -n/(2a))/(-n/a+n/(2a^2))\\
&= ( -1/(2a))/(-1/a+1/(2a^2))\\
&= ( a)/(2a-1)\\
\end{array}
$

so the
(hopefully)
more accurate $a$ is
$a_1
=a-a/(2a-1)
=a(1-1/(2a-1))
$
where,
as above,
$a
=e^{b+W}
$.

Comment: Thanks Marty, but a problem here is that $a$ is like around 7.

Comment: What does my approximation give? I don't know your values for $b$ and $W$.